# 'int' object is not subscriptable in queue

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I can't access the queue element inside the while loop in this code.
It  shows me

> 'int' object is not subscribable

But If I access it outside the while loop, it works fine.
Please give me an idea of how I can solve this problem.

Code:

```
queue.put([0,1])
sort_path[1]=0;
a = queue.get()
print(a[0])

While not queue.empty():
    N = queue.get()
    weight = N[0]
    node = N[1]
    for i in graph[node]:
        if(weight+i[1]<sort_path[i[0]]):
            sort_path[i[0]]=weight+i[1]
            queue.put(sort_path[i[0]],sort_path[i[0]])
print(sort_path)
```

[image: This error is displayed]

Comment: This error message tells you that the object `N` is an `int`, while you are trying to use `N[0]`, which is commonly used to access an item within a sequence or mapping. Furthermore your traceback does not match the code displayed as it contains no `int()` call. `print()` or otherwise investigate the value of `N`.

Comment: The error tells you that N is an int, not a tuple or a list.. Please post the code instead of posting images. I can't reproduce your problem from a picture.

Comment: When you have a problem with a variable, use the easy debug option `print(N)` to ensure the variable holds what you think

Comment: It seems that you get a value of N from the queue that is just a single integer, I guess this is not the data you were expecting

Comment: Why do you put a tuple of twice `sort_path[i[0]]` isn't there a typo here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a `tuple` use parenthesis as you did well on first line

```
queue.put((sort_path[i[0]], sort_path[i[0]]))
```

For now regarding the doc of [`queue.put`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put) you're using second parameter `block`